# Accessing a member of a union after another member has a value

Tags: c, language-lawyer, union

In C90 6.3.2.3p5 (with my emphasis)

> **With one exception, if a member of a union object is accessed after a value has been stored in
> a different member of the object, the behavior is implementation-defined.”** One special
> guarantee is made in order to simplify the use of unions: If a union contains several structures
> that share a common initial sequence (see below), and if the union object currently contains one
> of these structures, it is permitted to inspect the common initial part of any of them. Two
> structures share a *common initial sequence* if corresponding members have compatible types (and
> for bit-fields, the same widths) for a sequence of one or more initial members.

The bold part isn't seen after C90. And I think the empty space is substituted for detailed aliasing rule and effective type. But I don't know whether the bold part is now well defined.

```
float test1( float *fp, unsigned *uip)
{
  *fp = 1.0f;
  *uip += 1;
  return *fp;
}

union { float f; unsigned ui} u;

float test2(void)
{
  return test1(&u.f, &u.ui);
}
```

In the function `test1`, using the pointer `fp` to access the member of the union is implementation-defined according to C90. 
But is this now well defined regardless of implementation?
Can I know which part is related to understand this situation?

Comment: What you're doing is essentially [*type punning*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning) using the union, and in C it's allowed (unlike in C++ where it isn't).

Comment: `is this now well defined regardless of implementation?` Is "implementation-defined" a "well defined" or not "well defined" behavior? What do you mean by "now"?

Comment: @KamilCuk Sorry, I think "implementation-defined" is well defined. And in that question I meant "is this well defined regardless of implementation after C90?"